# Spigot Material WOOL doesn't exist anymore

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a big spigot plugin with a menu made with an inventory, and in this inventory, I add wools like choices for the player.

I use the following line to create my ItemStack:

```
ItemStack i = new ItemStack(Material.WOOL);
```

But I have the following error since spigot was updated in 1.13:

```
WOOL cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Does someone know why, and how to update through the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spigot 1.13, Materials are a little bit different, and each color of Wool got it's own name.

More information: [Spigot documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Material.html)

---

For instance, if you need a White Wool (It was the default color for `Material.WOOL`), you'll need `Material.WHITE_WOOL`, and your code will be:

`ItemStack i = new ItemStack(Material.WHITE_WOOL);`